# Is there a way to copy NSObject's properties?

Tags: ios

I want to implement a method that can copy object's property from A to B.For example

> A's name = @"a",
>
> A's code = @"1",
>
> A's address = 0x100(fake).

And after I use

> B's name = @"b",
>
> B's code = @"2",
>
> B's address = 0x200.

After I use the custom copy method,

> A = [A copyWith:B];

Now

> A's name = @"b",
>
> A's code = @"2",

but

> A's address = 0x100

does not change.

Code:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
@interface MyObject : NSObject
@property (copy, nonatomic) NSString *name;
@property (copy, nonatomic) NSString *code;
@end
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Conform to [`NSCopying`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSCopying_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/NSCopying) and implement `copyWithZone:` (which is called when you call the `copy` method).

Comment: @Rob I have tried, but A's address will change

Comment: If you conform to `NSCopying` and then say `MyObject *a = [b copy];`, `a` will have new, address.

Comment: @Rob  I know, but this is what I want to avoid. I just want to change the property but keep the pointer.

Comment: OK, I understand what you're asking for, but I'm unclear why you don't just write a method that updates the properties of `a` to be the valuesof the properties of `b`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use objc/runtime. Fetch all the objc_propertis from the new object and use `KVC` to set the value for the old object

Answer (score 0):

Then just drop NSCopying and write your own copy method something like:

```
-(void)copyMyObjectTo:(MyObject*)obj{

    obj.name = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",self.name];
    obj.code = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",self.code];
}
```

and call it:

```
[B copyMyObjectTo:A];
```

it should work

And like **@Rob** said there isn't a need to create new string objects if you leave your properties with **copy**

Comment: Since `name` and `code` are `copy` properties, the `stringWithFormat` stuff should be unnecessary.